# Как развернуть asp.net core + ms sql server в docker

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, docker

Следуя инструкции https://habr.com/ru/company/microsoft/blog/435914/ создал image и загрузил на dockerhub. Затем пытаюсь запустить docker run -it -p 5000:80 image_name и выдает ошибку "SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"
как я понял нужно еще задеплоить sql server и как то изменить connection string. Подскажите порядок действий или где можно почитать про это?

Comment: ого..) А вы запускаете `core +sql` в одном контейнере, в оркестре, или в разных? покажите как конфигурите (Dockerfile), как билдите, как запускаете (опишите подробнее). с версиями ничего не напутали? Когда запустите контейнер с `Sql`, попробуйте через любую морду подключиться к нему, после проверьте строку подключения к базе в коре (совпадает ли пользователь, название и т д

Comment: использую docker desktop. В контейнере запускается, как я понял, только само приложение. sql server установлен на той же машине, что и docker, возможно ли приложению из контейнера подключиться к нему? dockerfile сгенерирован visual studio. build запускаю из консоли. Какой адрес сервера должен быть в строке подключения?     "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-1PQ315D\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=url;User=sa;Password=*******"

Comment: `Data Source=127.2.3.4\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=dbase;User ID=sa;Password=password` только замените на свои значения (ip поставте локальный для машины, на которой Sql стоит )

Comment: Data Source = localhost\SQLEXPRESS,1433 подойдет? и что такое 1433?

Comment: 1433 - это порт (по дефолту). У вас может быть другой

Comment: Спасибо. При внесении изменений в код visual studio может запускать build образа и деплоить в контейнер или каждый раз нужно вводить команды вручную?

Comment: Когда вы подключаете Docker (с оркестром) к своей программе, создается как бы еще один проект и он запускается. При запуске он запускает `build`, а после `run` автоматически. И когда программа полностью запустилась вы это можете проверить командой `docker ps `

Answer (score 6):

Если у вас ASP.NET Core приложение запускается как контейнер, а SQL Server стоит на хост машине (той где запущен docker), то для доступа к SQL Server нужно использовать не название машины (`DESKTOP-1PQ315D`), а `host.docker.internal` (например `host.docker.internal\SQLServer` или что-то похожее). Docker, через встроенный DNS, автоматически подменит его на нужный IP (в моем случае это было `192.168.65.2`). Такой способ будет работать только для Docker for Mac/Windows.

Comment: Спасибо. При внесении изменений в код visual studio может запускать build образа и деплоить в контейнер или каждый раз нужно вводить команды вручную?

Comment: Изменил строку подключения на     "DockerConnection": "Server=host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=url;User=sa;Password=********" - тоже самое не находит sql server
на локальной машине все запускается со строкой подключения     "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-1PQ315D\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=url;User=sa;Password=*******",
У меня как раз Docker desktop fo win

Comment: @AntonCharov А зачем вы переименовали DefaultConnection на DockerConnection? А если все же нужно поменять имя, вы точно поменяли его в Startup.cs? Ещё, что можно проверить, в SQL Server Express, возможно выключено возможность для tcp/ip connection и/или firewall блочит (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver15)