# Почему docker не видит MS SQL сервер,

Tags: sql-server, docker

Пытаюсь из C#.Net WebAPI приложения, упакованного в docker-контейнер, получить доступ к MS SQL серверу на локальной машине. Все советы перепробовал, в том числе и со stackoverflow - ничего не помогает!

Строка подключения вот такая:
*Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True; User ID=MyName;Password=MyPwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;*

- Разрешил в Windows брандмауэре TCP через порт 1433.
- MSSQL сервер настроил на внешние подключения: оставил только TCP/IP, запретив
  Shared Memory и Named Pipe.
- Создал пользователя специально для этого
  случая.
- Выбрал аутентификацию Windows и SQL сервер. Подключение через
  аутентификацию SQL сервера проходит.

Но всё равно, при обращении из docker-контейнера получаю ошибку:

*Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.*

Что ещё я упустил? Почему недоступен MSSQL сервер?

P.S. Пока формулировал вопрос, ошибка стала появляться вот такая:
*Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\АНОНИМНЫЙ ВХОД'.*

Это мне вообще непонятно!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052394/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-asp-net-core-ms-sql-server-%d0%b2-docker/1052545#1052545

Comment: Спасибо, приятель, сработало! Только ещё нужно было отключить Trusted_Connection.